# How do I test the integration between the Global error handling middleware and my controller in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I'm trying to write some test with XUnit, specifically I'd like to have a test that ensures that when a certain exception is thrown it gets remapped into a meaningful error code. 
I already set up the Global error handling middleware and it works correctly. 
Here there is some example code of how my solution works:

My controller with a post endpoint that can return 200 or 404

```
//Controller
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> Create([FromBody] Request request) {
    //Process request
    handler.Handle(request);
    return Ok();
}
```

The Middleware for the Global error handling that remaps exceptions into Error codes

```
//StartUp Middleware
app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => {
    builder.Run(handler: async context => {
        IExceptionHandlerFeature error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        if (error != null) {
            int statusCode = (int)GetStatusCodeForException(error.Error);
            context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails { StatusCode = statusCode, Message = error.Error.Message }.ToString());
        }
    });
});
```

And then my test in where I arrange some mocks, instantiate the controller and call the Create method

```
//UnitTest
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockHandler = new Mock<IHandler>();
    mockHandler.Setup(handler => handler.Handle(It.IsAny<Request>())).Throws(new CustomException(It.IsAny<string>()));

    MyController myController = new MyController();

    //Act
    var statusCodeResult = await myController.Create(request);

    //Assert
    StatusCodeResult result = Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(statusCodeResult);
}
```

Here I want to ensure that the CustomException is remapped into a 404 status code. How do I do it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your test the middleware is not available. You need to spin up a hosting environment to do that, the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` provides you with one that you can use for testing:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task Test1()
{
    using var host = new TestServer(Program.CreateHostBuilder(null));
    var client = host.CreateClient();

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/controller");

    var result = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

    var status = result.StatusCode;

    // TODO: assertions
}
```

Now when you call your API in a way an exception is thrown, the middleware should be executed and covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`WebApplicationFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing nuget package. This bootstraps your application in-memory to allow for end to end functional tests. Rather than calling individual action methods you can make calls via `HttpClient` to ensure all middleware etc is called.

You use the `Startup` class that you have already defined in your main entry project and can add mock/fake objects to the IoC container as required. This allows you to verify/setup any dependencies.

You can then inject this as an `IClassFixture`. Once injected calling `.CreateClient()` on the instance will return an `HttpClient`, through which you can make requests.

Here is an example implementation:

```
// app factory instance
public class TestAppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    // mock for setup/verify
    public Mock<IHandler> MockHandler { get; } = new Mock<IHandler>();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton(MockHandler);
        });
    }
}

public class MyTestClass : IClassFixture<TestAppFactory>
{
    private readonly TestAppFactory _factory;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly Mock<IHandler> _mockHandler;

    public MyTestClass(TestAppFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
        _mockHandler = factory.MockHandler;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        // make calls via _client
    }
}
```